# sql selecting unique rows based on a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an table like this :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
asasa   1          d    44
asasa   2         sd    34
asasa   3          f    3
dssd    4          d    2
sdsdsd  5         sd    11
dssd    1         dd    34
xxxsdsds2          d    3
erewer  3          sd   3
```

I am trying to filter out something like this based on `Col1`

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
asasa   1          d    44
dssd    4          d    2
sdsdsd  5         sd    11
xxxsdsds2          d    3
erewer  3         sd    3
```

I am trying to get the all unique rows based on the values in `Col1`. If I have duplicates in `Col1`, the first row should be taken.

I tried `SELECT Col1 FROM tblname GROUP BY Col1` and got unique `Col1` but extending it using `*` is giving me error.

Comment: have you tried SELECT DISTINCT * from tblname

Comment: The other columns are not available because they are not in the group by. It also doesn't make sense to have them because they are different. So your example result shows the first record of each group

Comment: Every row is unique But Col1 will have duplicates. I want filter out the unique rows based on Col1

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? The solution might depend on which platform/SQL dialect is used.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: How do you decide which row to keep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @VJD Thanks for the upvote (assuming that was you). If the answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer. That way future visitors to the question can easily find which answer helped you resolve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your goal using something like the following:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS rn FROM MyTable
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

What it does is it creates a CTE (Common Table Expression) that adds a ROW_NUMBER on Col1, ordered by the data in row2.

In the outer select, we then only grab the rows from the CTE where the row number generated is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITIAN BY Col1 ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))RN 
FROM tblname
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the flavor of SQL that you have are using, what may help you are window functions.

In SQL Server, this can be accomplished with the `FIRST_VALUE` window function like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #vals;

CREATE TABLE #vals (COL1 VARCHAR(10), COL2 INT, COL3 VARCHAR(5), COL4 INT);

INSERT INTO #vals (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
VALUES ('asasa', 1, 'd', 44),
       ('asasa', 2, 'sd', 34),
       ('asasa', 3, 'f', 3),
       ('dssd' , 4, 'd', 2),
       ('sdsdsd', 5, 'sd', 11),
       ('dssd', 1, 'dd', 34),
       ('xxxsdsds', 2, 'd', 3),
       ('erewer', 3, 'sd', 3);

SELECT *
  FROM #vals

SELECT DISTINCT COL1, 
       FIRST_VALUE(COL2) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY Col1) AS Col2,
       FIRST_VALUE(COL3) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY Col1) AS Col3,
       FIRST_VALUE(COL4) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY Col1) AS Col4
  FROM #vals AS v1
```

This returns:

```
|COL1       |   Col2    |   Col3    |   Col4|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------|
|asasa      |   1       |   d       |   44  |
|dssd       |   4       |   d       |   2   |
|erewer     |   3       |   sd      |   3   |
|sdsdsd     |   5       |   sd      |   11  |
|xxxsdsds   |   2       |   d       |   3   |
```

which may then be `ORDER`ed in whatever way is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Select DISTINCT , should do the trick. Here is a good reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: But how to consider only Col1 ? I have unique rows all together but duplicates in Col1. if I do distinct I am going to get my first table shown above